# Android Webview in Dialog Drawing Issue

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have custom webview dialog for show agreement content. Content is coming from web service . It works my phone without any problem (Samsung Galaxy S4, 5.0.1)

But when I tried the diffrent phones, I realised a weird issue.

-Sony Z5 6.0

-Nexus 5 6.0

-General Mobile Android One 7.0

These devices have pure and nearly pure 6.0 and above Android OS, so It looks like Android problem. This problem not occurs on Samsung or Asus devices that I tested.

**My problem is content of the webwiew(not dialog, only webview) is drown twice and one of the drawing is located in bottom-left part of the whole screen area and even overlaying the navigation bar. Content is blurred intentionally :)**

[image]

DIALOG HELPER CLASS

```
public static void showWebviewDialog(final Context context, DialogModel model, final DialogCallback callback) {

        //Initialise Dialog
        dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.PauseDialogAnimation;
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_sozlesme);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);



        //Seting Data and callback ops
        ...
        //


        webViewDialog.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webViewDialog.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);
        webViewDialog.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

        final String htmlContent = model.getTvDesc();
        final String start = "<html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"user-scalable=no\"/><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html' charset='UTF-8' /><style>p {color:#707A8F;}\nimg.size-full{width:100%; height:auto;} iframe{width:100%; height:auto;} img{display: inline; height: auto; max-width: 100%;}</style></head><body>";
        final String end = "</body></html>";


        //Show Dialog
        dialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                webViewDialog.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, start + htmlContent + end, null, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
                webViewDialog.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                        pbSozlesmeDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        pbSozlesmeDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
```

MY ACTIVITY

```
 DialogHelper.showWebviewDialog(ActivityXX.this, dialogModel, dialogCallback);
```